# Strange behaviour in android

Tags: android, call, media-player

hi guys i have been struggling to find the reason for this strange behaviour. I have a service which will attend the incomming call and that code as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, event);

    ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(
            KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,
                    "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

And the above code works cool. And i have a activity from where i can play some simple audio file stored in the sdcard. And the code for that follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
        Uri data = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()+"/" + fileName);
        String type = "audio/mp3";
        intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and this too works fine. but the problem is that once the second activity thats to play is started and finished the first part to attend the call stops working. i dont know why it is happening like this. Can anybody tel the reason for that.

Comment: Hi Guys after a day of struggling found a solution. All that i did is instead of sending orderedBroadcast simply send the broadcast and it works fine now.... `ctx.sendBroadcast(i); instead of ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(i,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");`

Answer (score 2):

Pasting the comment to remove the question from unanswered. Please answer your own question next time.

> Hi Guys after a day of struggling found a solution. All that i did is
>   instead of sending orderedBroadcast simply send the broadcast and it
>   works fine now.... ctx.sendBroadcast(i); instead of
>   ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(i,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");